# Does it make sense to declare a doctype for an HTML fragment?

Tags: html, html-parsing, web-component, html5-template, html-imports

If I have an HTML5 component/WebComponent that has a `component.html` file that defines a `<template>`, does it make sense to have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration in `component.html`? That is, which of the following is best practice?

```
<template>
    <!-- some html content -->
</template>
```

Or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<template>
    <!-- some html content -->
</template>
```

Comment: A template is NOT an HTML page, but just a portion of HTML a small subset. So no Doctype is needed. Your code will read the template and insert it into an existing DOM which was provided by an HTML page. I would assume that you already provided a Doctype for that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both will be parsed and processed the same way in all modern browsers that support the `template` element.

One is a few octets lighter!

So it depends if you prefer speed over strict standards compliance

Following the KISS principle: The less code I write (and read), the better I feel ;-)